# What is the logic value of the following propositions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Assume that: $$ C \subset A $$ but $$ C \not\subset A \cap B $$ and $$B \cap C \neq \emptyset$$

How can I justify the following:

$A \neq \emptyset $  and $ B \neq \emptyset $

$A \cap B = B$

$\exists x \exists y (x \neq y $ and $x, y \in C)$

Comment: $A\cap B=B$ seems false : take $A=\{a,b,c\}$, $B=\{b,c,d\}$ and $C=\{a,b\}$. Then $C\subset A$, $C\not\subset A\cap B=\{b,c\}$ and $B\cap C\ne\emptyset$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nicolas pointed out the second statement is false. The other 2 are easily shown via proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The third claim $\exists x \exists y (x \neq y $ and $x, y \in C)$ can *also not* be proven from your givens: if $A = \{ a,b \}$, $B = \{ a\}$, and $C = \{ a \}$, then your givens is true but C does not contain two different elements, so $\exists x \exists y (x \neq y $ is false.

I suspect there may be some other given that you didn't post!

The first claim *can* be proven from your givens:

$A \neq \emptyset $  :  Given $C \subset A$ (meaning that $C$ is a *strict* subset of $A$), we have that $A$ contains some element(s) that are not contained in $C$, so $A$ is not empty.

and $ B \neq \emptyset $ : Given $B \cap C \neq \emptyset$, we know that there is some element common to both $B$ and $C$, so $B$ is not empty (and also $C$ is not empty)